# Basic command line?

Tags: unix, terminal

I want to run the following in terminal

```
compilervars.sh [-arch] <arch> [-platform <platform>]

  <arch> must be one of the following:
      ia32           : Set up for IA-32 target.
      intel64        : Set up for Intel(R)64 target.
  <platform> must be of the following:
      linux          : Set to Linux target.(default)
      mac            : Set to Mac target.
```

The target is intel64 and the platform mac.  I am in the correct directory.  Could someone please help with the basic syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Generally [square brackets] indicate an optional item.

Since you want to specify both the architecture (`intel64`) and the platform (`mac`), you need to specify both options, substitution for `<arch>` and for `<platform>` as appropriate:

```
compilervars.sh -arch intel64 -platform mac
```

This doesn't matter for your use case, but apparently the `<arch>` argument is mandatory, but the `-arch` flag preceding it is optional, so these:

```
compilervars.sh intel64
compilervars.sh -arch intel64
compilervars.sh intel64 -arch linux
compilervars.sh -arch intel64 -platform linux
```

are all equivalent (since `linux` is the default platform). In any case, it doesn't hurt to specify everything.

This all assumes the usage message is accurate.

Comment: Thanks all.  You are fantastic

Answer (score 0):

Revising with the edit to the question providing the full "help" output either of these should work:

```
./compilervars.sh -arch intel64 -platform mac
```

or

```
./compilervars.sh intel64 -platform mac
```

Comment: It wouldn't. Before my edit, the `<` and `>` characters were taken as HTML metacharacters, so the usage message wasn't shown properly in the question.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the corrected syntax from the command help output.  If it's not working, provide the exact error you're seeing.  .

Comment: I don't think your second command is valid. The `<platform>` is optional, but if it's there it must be preceded by `-platform`. Check the placement of the brackets in the help message (and my answer).

Comment: Oh, unrelated, you almost certainly want ia32.  intel64 is for itanium based machines, there was never an itanium based MAC.

Comment: I suspect `intel64` is `x86_64`, which is what modern Macs use.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the closing brace wrapping the whole second thing.

Comment: @alvits no it does not.  It stands for "intel architecture"